# MVC Authorize attribute must meet all requirements, is is possible to meet only one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have a view that I want to be able to be accessed by admins or specific users.  So I added this attribute.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin", Users = "john, jane, jim" )]
```

I was hoping that a user would be authorized if they met either the role OR the user.  But it seems to only authorize users that match both criteria.

Is it possible to handle it as an or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a custom authorize class that handles the unauthorized request and does it's own comparison.  I've also added a redirect to a custom unauthorized view instead of just throwing out a 401 error.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else if (!Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole) && !Users.Split(',').Any(ex => ex.ToLower().Trim() == filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToLower()))
        {
            // The user is not in any of the listed roles => 
            // show the unauthorized view
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just use `MyAuthorize` instead of `Authorize` in the attribute like so

```
[MyAuthorize(Users = "john, jane, tim", Roles = "admin")]
```